# I try to return a List type from AccessLayer to a datagrid on Windows form but get ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#, return, ienumerable, iqueryable

I am trying to keep developing my program in order to improve my knowledge on C#

But I am stuck again.

Problem is

I am trying to call a method inside Business layer in order to fill my product datagridview.

[here you can see my screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wynq5.jpg)

```
 public  List<Product> GetProductWithCategories()
        {
            using (DenemeContext context=new DenemeContext())
            {
                var query = (from pro in context.Products
                       join cat in context.Categories
                       on pro.CategoryId equals cat.CategoryId
                       select new
                       {
                           ProductID = pro.ProductId,
                           ProductName = pro.ProductName,
                           ProductCategor = cat.CategoryName
                       }).ToList();
                return query.ToList();
            }
```

I am getting an error in return of the query. I try to convert the query into Ienumerable as the method is a List method.

How can i get over this problem? ( I can list the table with put this code inside the main form, but I would like to take the result insied the Business layer).

[and you can check my codes on Github, if you wish](https://github.com/RadoHub/deneme/tree/master/Deneme.Entities)

thank you.

Comment: Where are you getting an `ArgumentNullException`?  The screen shot doesn't indicate that at all.  It *does* indicate a compiler error on that line with the red squiggle.  What is *that* error?  (It's *probably* an error about converting from an anonymous type to `Product`.)

Comment: The query variable is already List<T> since you are executing ToList() method right after the LINQ statement. This is why the compiler is complaining about the return statement.

Comment: @s.feradov: No it isn't.  You can call `.ToList()` as many times as you want, the compiler won't care.  There could be other issues depending on what's being enumerated, but not compiler errors.

Comment: @David Correct indeed. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify class name `Product` after `select new` statement. This will indicate compiler you return a list of concrete class. Without a class name you return a list of anonymous type which is not equal to `List<Product>`

```
public  List<Product> GetProductWithCategories()
{
    using (DenemeContext context=new DenemeContext())
    {
        var query = (from pro in context.Products
               join cat in context.Categories
               on pro.CategoryId equals cat.CategoryId
               select new Product
               {
                   ProductID = pro.ProductId,
                   ProductName = pro.ProductName,
                   ProductCategor = cat.CategoryName
               }).ToList();
        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for answer. But this is not a solution for me. Because I want to join two table and mark it as one table. But if I put new Product, compiler will say that Product class do not contain a ProductCategory property. https://imgur.com/a/BoNje9n here if I try to make this with void method under mainform.cs it is working, but I want to do it over Business layer. so I must return a value to fill categorydatagridview under form1.cs. but I am getting that error above.

Comment: Then you need to create a new class that will represent your `select` clause fields and use it instead of `Product`

Comment: so you mean, I must create a new model as a class ? I will try it. thank you.